# What is the best way to program C# on a free platform? (Compiler / IDE / Debugger / etc)

Tags: c#

Preferably also on linux - if necessary I'll install a basic version of Windows XP

Comment: Just saying  I'm interested in this also, the compiler for CSharp is free and all but I don't like being tied down to visual studio *always*.

Mono is not an alternative for me, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are going to install the XP on your linux machine then the Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition 2005 and 2008 are extremely good programs.  Infact I think all the express editions are amazing that they are free.

Answer (score 8):

No problem - [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Main_Page) will run were you want it -

> MonoDevelop is a free GNOME IDE primarily designed for C# and other .NET languages.

Comment: See the release note ( http://monodevelop.com/MonoDevelop_1.0_Released ) - no visual designer for ASP.NET pages. No WPF support, but moonlight is close ( http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight ).

Answer (score 4):

On Linux your only option is Mono and monodevelop. However Mono will not give you access to all libraries in the Microsoft .NET stack. Most notably things like WCF, WPF and WF won't be supported, and the recommended UI library to use is GTK#, as opposed to the more widely used WinForms or WPF.

On Windows you can go either for the free Visual Studio Express editions, or for sharpdevelop. Sharpdevelop naturally focuses more on integration with other free tools like NUnit and WiX, but for editing, refactoring and debugging I would say that Visual Studio express is still better feature wise. You an also find more plugins for VS.

Bottom line if you want "cutting edge" stuff you really need windows. Otherwise there's not much choice.

Answer (score 3):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

If you're considering serious (commercial) .NET development I wouldn't dive into products like Mono or Shardevelop.
One of the reasons why .NET might be a better option from Java, for example, is because Microsoft provides very nice and powerful tools for the development which makes the development process a lot easier. Using free/open tools  and implementations makes developing in .NET meaningless since Java in this area is much better.

Of course there's Express series, but those IDE are designated for learning mostly (you didn't say why do you need free tools). For the professional team development they are still not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a great IDE and apparently [there's a C# plug in for it](http://www.improve-technologies.com/alpha/esharp/). I've not used it however (the plugin) so I can't comment on its quality.